# how can I get the selected value of checkboxlist and passed that value from view to controller using jquery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

view:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Searchbyquality", "Health", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
     {
        foreach (var item in Model.QualityModel)
        {
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="qualitycheck"/><span>item.qualityName</span></li>
        }
   }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Searchbyquality(string[] qualitycheck )
{
           //code of searching

}
```

I want to pass multiple selected value to the controller

Comment: where is your controller action

Comment: Your checkbox does not contain a `name` attribute so wont post back anything

Comment: Please correct my checkbox

Comment: You have not shown your model or the controller methods so no one can help you.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

**Your View Code Should be :**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Searchbyquality", "Health", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
     {
    foreach (var item in Model.QualityModel)
                {
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   name="qualitycheck"
                                   value="@item.qualityName" /> @item.qualityName
                            </label>
                        </div>
                }
                @*<div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                </div>*@
}
```

**For without `Submit button` you have to add jQuery Code to call controller action :**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            var qualitycheck_data = { 'qualitycheck': [] };

            $('input:checked').each(function ()
            {
                if(this.name == 'qualitycheck') qualitycheck_data['qualitycheck'].push($(this).val());

            });
            var path = "/Health/Searchbyquality";
            $.ajax({
                url: path, type: "POST", cache: "false",
                dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(qualitycheck_data),
                traditional: true,
                converters: {'text json': true}
            }).success(function (responseText) {
               //Success result 
               window.location.assign(responseText); 
            }).error(function (responseText){
                swal("Error!", "Test 1", "error");
            });
            //swal("Error!", "Test 2", "error");
        }
    });
});
```

**And your Controller Action :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Searchbyquality(string[] qualitycheck )
{
           //code of searching
   return View("");
}
```

**cheers !!**

Comment: I don't want submit button...I want that when user select the checkbox that checkbox value will pass to controller and acc. to that searching will perform

Comment: like filter using checkbox

Comment: For that you require jquery ajax call check updated ANS

Comment: I want to implement like we do filters for e- commerce site

Comment: In your link it is passing multiple values after submit button,....but I don't want submit button..........If I applied your jquery that is good for single value

Comment: Did not get your question? How can we set event to checklist?

Comment: Than how the filtration performs in E-commerce websites

Comment: can do something by onclick ?

Comment: What is the problem here ?

Comment: It is not passing the value to the controller

Comment: In the previous jquery

Comment: you getting data in qualitycheck_data in ajax call but its not passing to controller action right ?

Comment: Try to modify that code and check again that will surly work for you

Comment: $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("SearchbyQuality", "Health")?chk_id=' + chb,
     type: "post"
     });

Comment: Please suggest the solution

Comment: for that code your controller action should be public ActionResult Searchbyquality(string chk_id)
{
           //code of searching

}

Comment: I just want to know that why it is not going in my given url?............First I will check for single value

Comment: Can we come on chat?

Comment: my replay button is not clickable

Comment: I think you do not have privileges to talk in chat room

Comment: need one more help...In your updated jquery in the //successresult how will I write the urlaction in windows.location.href

Comment: Use this code in success function : success(function (responseText) { window.location.assign(responseText); }    I have Updated my code as well

Comment: Getting this error Bad Request - Invalid URL

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

Comment: URL is not coming properly